# CRM 2013: Hide system ribbon button for selected entities

Tags: xml, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to hide a system button on the Advanced Find ribbon **for selected entities**. I have customized the application ribbon and added a display rule (OrRule) to check for the list of entities. However, I am not able to get the **InvertResult** property work for the rule so that the button will be hidden for these entities.

I have used the Ribbon workbench as well as tried editing the ribbon xml manually. Both did not work. With the workbench solution, I can edit the display rule properties and set the **InvertResult** property to True. However, the changes are not being saved/published. I don't know what I'm missing.

Can someone please help me solve this issue ?

Here is the DisplayRule

```
<DisplayRule Id="new.ApplicationRibbon.Subgrid.SystemDeactivate.DisplayRule">
      <OrRule>
        <Or>
          <EntityRule EntityName="new_fcall" AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" Context="SubGridStandard" />
        </Or>
        <Or>
          <EntityRule EntityName="new_plan" AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" Context="SubGridStandard" />
        </Or>
        <Or>
          <EntityRule EntityName="new_automaticnotification" AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" Context="SubGridStandard" />
        </Or>
</OrRule>
    </DisplayRule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used an alternative way to fix the problem. I defined different display rule (with entity rule)for each entity and used the InvertResult = true. So the display rules worked like and 'AND' condition and return false even if one of the display rule is false.